# How to remove the rows that returns 'Null' in the results in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I have a query that gives me the results as required. But I don't want the rows that displays 'Null' in the final results.

```
SELECT DISTINCT In_Time, 
    Out_Time,
    "Duration" = CASE
                    WHEN DATEDIFF (hh,In_Time, Out_Time) >= 2 
                       THEN 'Duration was GREATER than 2 hours'
                 END  
FROM 
    CASES  C
```

The result displayed:

| In_Time | Out_Time | Duration |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-04-01 09:05:21 | 2021-04-01 09:28:46 | NULL |
| 2021-04-01 09:31:37 | 2021-04-01 10:33:27 | NULL |
| 2021-04-01 08:56:00 | 2021-04-01 11:46:11 | duration was GREATER than 2 hours |
| 2021-04-02 12:50:00 | 2021-04-02 14:52:26 | duration was GREATER than 2 hours |
| 2021-04-02 16:10:57 | 2021-04-02 17:05:21 | NULL |

How to remove the rows that returns null and get the results as below

Expected result :

| In_Time | Out_Time | Duration |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-04-01 08:56:00 | 2021-04-01 11:46:11 | duration was GREATER than 2 hours |
| 2021-04-02 12:50:00 | 2021-04-02 14:52:26 | duration was GREATER than 2 hours |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps it's simplest just to include a `WHERE` clause for that:

```
WHERE DATEDIFF (hh,In_Time, Out_Time) >= 2
```

And in the original SQL:

```
SELECT DISTINCT In_Time, 
        Out_Time,
        CASE
          WHEN DATEDIFF (hh,In_Time, Out_Time) >= 2 THEN 'Duration was GREATER than 2 hours'
        END AS [Duration]
  FROM  CASES C 
  WHERE DATEDIFF (hh,In_Time, Out_Time) >= 2
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest:

```
SELECT DISTINCT In_Time, Out_Time,
      'Duration was GREATER than 2 hours' as Duration
FROM CASES C 
WHERE DATEDIFF(hour, In_Time, Out_Time) >= 2;
```

Including the string the `SELECT` seems redundant, though, because all the values are the same.

Another approach is to put the definition of `DURATION` in the `FROM` clause so you can use the value in multiple places:

```
SELECT DISTINCT c.In_Time, c.Out_Time, v.Duration
FROM CASES C CROSS APPLY
     (VALUES (CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(hour, c.In_Time, c.Out_Time) >= 2
                   THEN 'Duration was GREATER than 2 hours'
              END)
     ) v(Duration)
WHERE v.Duration IS NOT NULL;
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the Answers.

I got the Answer when I used the below query

```
SELECT DISTINCT In_Time, 
    Out_Time,
    "Duration" = 
    CASE
WHEN DATEDIFF (hh,In_Time, Out_Time) >= 2 THEN 'Duration was GREATER than 2 hours'
    END  
    FROM CASES  C
WHERE DATEDIFF(hour, In_Time, Out_Time) >= 2
```